# ggplot in a function: variable not found

Tags: r, data-visualization, ggplot2

I have an issue trying to create a function to creat a plot using ggplot. Here is some code:

```
y1<- sample(1:30,45,replace = T)
x1 <- rep(rep(c("a1","a2","a3","a4","a5"),3),each=3)
x2 <- rep(rep(c("b1","b2","b3","b4","b5"),3),each=3)
df <- data.frame(y1,x1,x2)
library(Rmisc)
dfsum <- summarySE(data=df, measurevar="y1",groupvars=c("x1","x2"))
myplot <- function(d,v, w,g) {
  pd <- position_dodge(.1)
  localenv <- environment()
  ggplot(data=d, aes(x=v,y=w,group=g),environment = localenv) + 
  geom_errorbar(data=d,aes(ymin=d$w-d$se, ymax=d$w+d$se,col=d$g), width=.4, position=pd,environment = localenv) +
  geom_line(position=pd,linetype="dotted") +
  geom_point(data=d,position=pd,aes(col=g))
}
myplot(dfsum,x1,y1,x2)
```

As I was looking for similar questions, I found that specifying the local environment should solve the issue. However it did not help in my case.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Preliminary Note**

When looking at your `data.frame`, the `group` variable does not make any sense, as it is perfectly confounded with the x variable. Hence I adapted your data a bit, to show a full example:

**Data**

```
library(Rmisc)
library(ggplot2)
d <- expand.grid(x1 = paste0("a", 1:5),
                 x2 = paste0("b", 1:5))
d <- d[rep(1:NROW(d), each = 3), ]
d$y1 <- rnorm(NROW(d))
dfsum <- summarySE(d, measurevar = "y1", groupvars = paste0("x", 1:2))
```

**Plot Function**

```
myplot <- function(mydat, xvar, yvar, grpvar) {
   mydat$ymin <- mydat[[yvar]] - mydat$se
   mydat$ymax <- mydat[[yvar]] + mydat$se
   pd <- position_dodge(width = .5)
   ggplot(mydat, aes_string(x = xvar, y = yvar, group = grpvar,
                            ymin = "ymin", ymax = "ymax", color = grpvar)) +
      geom_errorbar(width = .4, position = pd) +
      geom_point(position = pd) + 
      geom_line(position = pd, linetype = "dashed")
}
myplot(dfsum, "x1", "y1", "x2")
```

**Explanation**

Your problem occurs because the scope of `x1` `x2` and `y1` was ambiguous. As you defined these variables also at the top environmnet, `R` did not complain in the first place. If you had added a `rm(x1, x2, y1)`in your original code right after you created your `data.frame` you would have seen the problem already eralier.

`ggplot` looks in the `data.frame` you provide for all the variables you want to map to certain aesthetics. If you want to create a function, where you specify the name of the aesthatics as arguments, you should use `aes_string` instead of `aes`, as the former expects a string giving the name of the variable rather than the variable itself.

With this approach however, you cannot do calculations on the spot, so you need to create the variables `ymin`and `ymax`beforehand in your `data.frame`. Furthermore, you do not need to provide the data argument for each geom if it is the same as provided to `ggplot`.

Comment: Thank you very much for this clear explanation. I am sorry that the provided code did not fit well the purpose. I tried with my original data set and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I've got it plotting something, let me know if this isn't the expected output.

[image: plot]

The changes I've made to the code to get it working are:

- Load the ggplot2 library
- Remove the `d$` from the geom_errorbar call to `w` and `g`, as these are function arguments rather than columns in `d`.

I've also removed the `data=d` calls from all layers except the main `ggplot` one as these aren't necessary.

```
library(ggplot2)
myplot <- function(d,v, w,g) {
  pd <- position_dodge(.1)
  localenv <- environment()
  ggplot(data=d, aes(x=v,y=w,group=g),environment = localenv) +
    geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=w-se, ymax=w+se,col=g), width=.4,
              position=pd,environment = localenv) +
    geom_line(position=pd,linetype="dotted") +
    geom_point(position=pd,aes(col=g))
}
myplot(dfsum,x1,y1,x2)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. It works with the training code, but not with my original data set where I get again "y1 not found". The suggestion of thothal is working well.